# Does this while condition read the line?

Tags: c++

I reading this book and it had this while statement condition,

```
while(!inFile.getline(readLine, MAX_CHARACTERS, '\n').eof())
```

I know what the condition means, I just want to know if it reads the line and stores it into my variable, and therefore don't have to use inFile.getline another time to get the same line?

In other words I don't want to re-read the same line twice or even skip a line.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried testing it yourself?

Comment: What did you observe, when running that code?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the condition to be evaluated, getline() must be executed, and that execution, if successful would have to read the text from the stream and store it in readLine. Have you tried it?